# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [120, 30]

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model, xgboost, mse

I practice XGBClassifier() to predict the target in iris dataset.
here  is the code:

```
#iris dataset, set data to X and target to y
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
```

```
#import datasets from sklearn, train_test_split from sklearn.model_selection
X_train, x_test , y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)

model = XGBClassifier(n_estimators = 100, learning_rate = 0.1,verbosity = 1, random_state = 1)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as MSE
rmse = np.sqrt(MSE(y_train,y_pred))
print(rmse)
```

when I use mean_squared_error from sklean.metrics I get an error

**ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [120, 30]**

Comment: You are comparing the ground truth values of your training set with the predicted values on your test set, which is impossible since they have a different number of observations. Make sure to compare to use the same data split in both instances.